# IE Explorer 9 not rendering until after ajax/json function has complete

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

Basically I have this code.  I am trying to simply update a div but the first innerHTML call either does not work or never renders in the browser.

The second one does work though which appends "Complete" once the ajax call is complete.  I'm sure it has something to do with the ajax call but I don't see why this is happening because in Firefox there is no issue.  Does anyone know what is wrong or if there is a bug in firefox or something?  Why would IE even be waiting to render the innerHTML call.  Shouldn't the div be updated right after the call or does IE explorer wait a bit?

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '<div>Loading</div>';

$jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST", 
         url: urlValue, 
         data: parameters, 
         cache: false,
         async: false, 
         dataType: "json"
});

document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '<div>Complete</div>';
```

Comment: Ugh, why are you doing it like this? What's wrong with a normal callback?

Comment: This isn't 100% of the code.  The $jQuery.ajax call is actually run inside of a function and there is a success call.  And the callback has nothing to do with the error that's occuring.  The document is not rendering a call that is made before the ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do it asynchronously?

```
var status = $('#status');

status.html('<div>Loading</div>');

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: urlValue, 
    data: parameters, 
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        status.html('<div>Complete</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: But why would that affect the DOM not rendering something that is completed before the ajax call is even made?  And only in IE?

Comment: @Ray: Why not just do it the right way and forget about the behaviour of IE because of the wrong usage of A(synchronus)JAX?

Answer (score 0):

try to execute those code on load complete. 
Possibly in moment when

```
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '<div>Loading</div>';
```

executed DOM is not ready for accessing it.

1. On DOM ready - putting "Loading Value"
2. Making ajax request ("loading is displayed till it will ends")
3. Once it will ends, setting "Complete"

Anyway till DOM is ready you can not change it. Except document.write, but it's little bit another story.

Probably that will help

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '<div>Loading</div>';},0);

ajax post request ...
```

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do.  I want the div to say "Loading" while the ajax call is being made.

Comment: 1. On DOM ready - putting "Loading Value"
2. Making ajax request ("loading is displayed till it will ends")
3. Once it will ends, setting "Complete" 

Or just put "loading " on the server side.

Comment: All of this is happening inside the $jQuery(document).ready(function() so I don't think that's the problem.  Also, if I remove the ajax call that happens after the innerHTML call then it appends to the document fine.

Comment: try to use 

setTimeout(function(){... assign inner html}, 0);

and then ajax call. Or ajax call inside of Timeout function.